# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kk.COUNTRY cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb, classcastexception, unmarshalling

**My main class is**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException,
        FileNotFoundException {

    Class[] classes = new Class[5];
    classes[0] = com.kk.AddressDetails.class;
    classes[1] = com.kk.COUNTRY.class;
    classes[2] = com.kk.ObjectFactory.class;
    classes[3] = com.kk.Details.class;
    classes[4] = com.kk.Districts.class;

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<COUNTRY> unmarshal = (JAXBElement<COUNTRY>) unmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new File("src\\countrydetails.xml"));
    COUNTRY value = unmarshal.getValue();
            System.out.println(value);
```

So while compiling this i got this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kk.COUNTRY cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    at main.kk.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:31)

Comment: java is case sensitive. I suspect COUNTRY should be com.kk.Country.class

Comment: Is `COUNTRY` root of xml file ?

Comment: @Bhavik Shah: no it is COUNTRY

Comment: @TheNewIdiot yes COUNTRY is the root of xml

Answer (score 3):

Since your `COUNTRY` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` it means it is uniquely associated with a root element and  the result of the unmarshal operation will be `COUNTRY`

```
COUNTRY c = (COUNTRY) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

If instead `COUNTRY` had one or more corresponding `@XmlElementDecl` annotations or you used an `unmarshal` method that took a `Class` parameter you would get an instance of `JAXBElement`

```
JAXBElement<COUNTRY> c = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, COUNTRY.class);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Unmarshaller.unmarshal(File f)` returns an `Object` and not `JAXBElement`.

Here is the signature:

```
public Object unmarshal( java.io.File f ) throws JAXBException;
```

Your solution should be:

```
COUNTRY value = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("src\\countrydetails.xml")), COUNTRY.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not cast the unmarshl result to JAXBElement, it should simply be your COUNTRY class that you are trying to unmarshal. Assuming you have properly annotated your COUTNRY class then you can simply do this:

```
COUNTRY unmarshal = (COUNTRY) unmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new File("src\\countrydetails.xml"));
```

Follow this tutorial to learn about JAXB marshalling and unmarshalling through simple example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/